# Intermittent problem calling GetExternalFilesDir in Android

Tags: android, xamarin

In my Xamarin Android app I save various bits of data (for example logging and errors) to the external files directory. To do this I call GetExternalFilesDir in the below method:

```
using AndroidApp = Android.App;
...  
private string GetExternalPrivateStoragePath()
    {

            return AndroidApp.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(null).AbsolutePath;
    }
```

This is called very frequently in production - several times a minute. 
Very occasionally I will get a null reference exception from this method. After this exception all subsequent calls also return a null reference exception until the app is restarted. My question is, under what circumstances would this throw a null reference exception, and how can I recover from it? The app is currently only being used on the same model of Android device which has an internal shared storage directory, which contains the path returned by the above method. The app is used in an industrial setting where it is used constantly, and it is unlikely it is restarted for days at a time.
This is information I have received from the error report in App Center:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Main thread
TecMan.MobileApp.Android.Wrappers.FileWrapper.GetExternalPrivateStoragePath()
TecMan.MobileApp.Android.Wrappers.FileWrapper.GetItemPath (System.String,itemname, System.Boolean useExternalStorage)
TecMan.MobileApp.Android.Wrappers.FileWrapper.CreateDirectory (System.String directory, System.Boolean useExternalStorage)
```

Comment: Does your APP have special handling for catching exceptions? If so, you can view these error logs to analyze the root cause of the error.

Comment: I get a log of the stack trace, time and exception type. I don't get the Android log as the whole app hasn't fallen over.

Comment: You can post the log here, so that others could help you better.